# Broken tip on my Leland Spruce

Tags: trees

I have a 10 foot tall Leyland spruce where the tip (approx 6 inches)was broke and hanging down due to an ice storm. Will it grow any taller after I trim it off?

Answer (score 2):

After the top part of the central leader of a Leyland spruce is broken, the tree will grow multiple leaders. These leaders compete for dominance, but often the result is several leaders growing alongside. This leads to the loss of the slender shape of the tree, and result in a V-shaped or further irregular shaped tree, which may be problematic, e.g., during snowfall.

So, it is recommended that after multiple leaders are developed, those be allowed to grow up to a point, and when it is clear that the healthiest or the most beautiful of those leaders will thrive further, the rest are trimmed off.

There are even [guides](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/cut-top-leyland-cypress-trees-67225.html) about how to cut back the top of Leyland cypress trees.

Comment: Great advice! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, @Jeff :)

Answer (score 1):

It will develop another leader, maybe a few, and continue grow.

Comment: Whew! Thank you!